# Why PHP doesnt let me access this object's properties

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, object

```
include 'businessLogic.php';
session_start();

$user_email = $_SESSION["user_email"];


//creates new object
$user_obj[] = new stdClass();

//returns a single user
$user_obj[] = getUser($user_email);


$user_id= $user_obj[0]->user_id;

$password= $user_obj[0]->password;

$email= $user_obj[0]->email;  

$date_of_birth= $user_obj[0]->date_of_birth;    

$gender= $user_obj[0]->gender;

$first_name= $user_obj[0]->first_name;

$last_name= $user_obj[0]->last_name;
```

This produces same error for all properties

`Undefined property: stdClass::$user_id in`

Comment: `var_dump($user_obj)`

Answer (score 1):

Take a close look:

You push an `stdClass` object into the array `$user_obj`

```
//creates new object
$user_obj[] = new stdClass();
```

It will receive index 0.

Then you push a user object.

```
//returns a single user
$user_obj[] = getUser($user_email);
```

It is at index 1.

But you try to access it at index 0. Correct it must be:

```
$user_id = $user_obj[1]->user_id;
//...
```

Comment: got rid of $user_obj[] = new stdClass();
and still get Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\wam

Comment: @TomerHenn `getUser($user_email);` apparently doesn't return an object. What does `var_dump(getUser($user_email));` show?

Comment: it returns this array (size=1)
  0 => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => 
        object(stdClass)[3]
          public 'user_id' => string '1' (length=1)
          public 'password' => string '12345' (length=5)
          public 'email' => string 'aaa@aaa.com' (length=11)
          public 'date_of_birth' => string '0000-00-00' (length=10)
          public 'gender' => string 'male' (length=4)
          public 'first_name' => string 'kipi' (length=4)
          public 'last_name' => string 'ben-kipod' (length=9)

Comment: Try `$user_id = $user_obj[0][0]->user_id;`

Comment: still not recognizing $user_obj as an object and throws  Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\wamp\www\social_network\editUser.php on line 16

Comment: I think I forgot one accessor, try instead this: `$user_id = $user_obj[0][0][0]->user_id;`

Comment: now getting this ( ! ) Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in C:\wamp\www\social_network\editUser.php on line 16

Comment: @TomerHenn Which line is 16? What are you trying to do there?

Comment: $user_id = $user_obj[0][0][0]->user_id; this one is 16. the function get user btw returns an array with one object which var_dump shows is there so why cant i access it ?

Answer (score 0):

Since `$user_obj` is an array, its index 0 is initialized with a `new stdClass` object.

```
$user_obj[] = new stdClass();
```

and in this statement, the object which is returned by the function is assigned to index 1 of the array `$user_obj`.

```
//returns a single user
$user_obj[] = getUser($user_email);
```

There is no meaning in the first initialization that you have made here. It is just a blank object of `stdClass`.